# Cloud9 IDE to run python3 with venv

Tags: python, virtualenv, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to use a custom runner in `Cloud9` to launch a project under `python 3.4` using a virtual environment installed in the same directory, but it doesn't work. The runner doesn't detect my dependencies, which presumably means it isn't activating the `venv` properly.

```
// Create a custom Cloud9 runner - similar to the Sublime build system
// For more information see https://docs.c9.io/custom_runners.html
{
  "cmd": [
    "bash",
    "--login",
    "-c",
    "source bin/activate && python oric.py"
  ],
  "working_dir": "$project_path",
  "info": "Your code is running at \\033[01;34m$url\\033[00m.\n\\033[01;31m"
}
```

Any thoughts on what's wrong? Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

From start to finish:

1. Create a virtual environment:

> ```
> $ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python36 vpy36
> ```

2. Install Python package into virtual environment:

> ```
> $ source vpy36/bin/activate
> $ pip3 install tweepy
> ```

3. Create Runner:

- Navigate the menu to create the runner

[image]

- Create .run File

Copy and paste the example code below into your .run file. This will allow both normal and debug executions of your venv.

```
// This file overrides the built-in Python 3 runner
// For more information see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/cloud9/change-runner
{
  "script": [
    "if [ \"$debug\" == true ]; then ",
    "    /home/ec2-user/environment/venvpy36/bin/python -m ikp3db -ik_p=15471 -ik_cwd=$project_path \"$file\" $args",
    "else",
    "   /home/ec2-user/environment/venvpy36/bin/python \"$file\" $args",
    "fi",
    "checkExitCode() {",
    "    if [ $1 ] && [ \"$debug\" == true ]; then ",
    "        /home/ec2-user/environment/venvpy36/bin/python -m ikp3db 2>&1 | grep -q 'No module' && echo '",
    "    To use python debugger install ikpdb by running: ",
    "        sudo yum update;",
    "        sudo yum install python36-devel;",
    "        sudo source /home/ec2-user/environment/venvpy36/bin activate",
    "        sudo pip-3.6 install ikp3db;",
    "        sudo deactivate",
    "        '",
    "    fi",
    "   return $1",
    "}",
    "checkExitCode $?"
  ],
  "python_version": "/home/ec2-user/environment/venvpy36/bin/python",
  "working_dir": "$project_path",
  "debugport": 15471,
  "$debugDefaultState": false,
  "debugger": "ikpdb",
  "selector": "^.*\\.(py)$",
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "$python_path"
  },
  "trackId": "/home/ec2-user/environment/venvpy36/bin/python"
}
```

**If you placed your venv in a different directory during step 1** Find and replace all references of "/home/ec2-user/environment/venvpy36/bin" with your own venv bin directory and the code should work for you.

4. Finally, Save the file

Select the Runner and Run the File:
Select your runner (in this example, "vpy36"). Then click "Run" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I use virtualenv on Cloud9 and it works fine for me. Cloud9 workspaces seem to come with virtualenv wrapper pre-installed (at least, Django workspace does), so if you create a virtualenv with:

```
$ mkvirtualenv foo
```

Then, you can create your runner like so, for example:

```
{
  "cmd": [
    "bash",
    "--login",
    "-c",
    "source /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/activate && python whatever.py"
  ],
  # ... rest of the configuration
}
```

Comment: No need to activate, @Joshua answer is more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I got cloud9 to use virtualenv by just setting the environment vars directly instead of trying to source the activate script.

```
{
  "cmd": [
    "/var/lib/cloud9/venv/bin/python",
    "$file",
    "$args"
  ],
  "selector": "^.*\\.(python|py)$",
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "/var/lib/cloud9/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages",
    "VIRTUAL_ENV": "/var/lib/cloud9/venv",
    "PATH": "/var/lib/cloud9/venv/bin:$PATH"
  }
}
```

Comment: How would we allow this to be used in debug mode?

Comment: I actually switched to VSC remote instead of c9 so, I don't know.

Comment: You do not need to set any env vars.

Comment: What file is that you showed? Seriously this is your answer?

Comment: I'm sorry @doug65536 for the lack of detail.  It was in a configuration region somewhere.  When you figure it out could you be the hero and add a comment as to where?

Comment: @doug65536: Run>Run Configurations>New Run Configuration. Then, next to the bug icon, there is a dropdown "Run:Auto". Click on it and select "New Runner". Then, you can paste the JSON provided by Joshua. Make sure you adapt the paths to point to the correct venv.